# Parsley.js change box-shadow and border-color based on input

Tags: jquery, css, html, forms, parsley.js

On the [parsley.js documentation page](http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html), the classy demo has an implementation of adding a red border and box-shadow if the input did not pass validation. How can I implement this same feature? I looked at the css being applied on the :focus state of the "Full Name" input and found that a bootstrap class is added, but I cannot figure out how.

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add the following CSS-Class to your input:

```
input.parsley-error
    {
      color: #B94A48 !important;
      background-color: #F2DEDE !important;
      border: 1px solid #EED3D7 !important;
    }
```

Comment: that works, but I think there's also a focus, which I can just add too. Thanks.